# Sql Where Contains textbox skillevel and skillname

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My users can save skill level from 1 star to 4 stars and skillname for example C#,C++ and so an
My query looks like this

```
var searchTechSkill = from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                      join ets in db.EMPLOYEES_TECHNICAL_SKILLS on p.employee_id equals ets.employee_id
                      join ts in db.TECHNICAL_SKILLS_VALUES on ets.technical_skill_value_id equals ts.technical_skill_value_id
                      join tsl in db.TECHNICAL_SKILL_LEVEL on ets.technical_skill_level_id equals tsl.technical_skill_level_id
                      **where ts.skill_name.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) &&
                            tsl.skill_level.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text)** ||
                            ets.skill_name_other.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) ||
                            ts.skill_type.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text)
```

[image]

Byt when I Search I don't get any values? how should I write the where query to be able from one textbox get the value from skillname and skillevel doing like in my image because when I use && I don't get anything to display, but when using || al the way in the query I can only search for one thing at time

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well you search for the full content of the textbox in both fields. You need to split the text in the textbox individual strings and search for those.

You search for skill name = "c# *********. You probably meant to search for "c#" instead

Comment: what is the content of your skill name "c#" or "c# ***" -> there is your problem